# Combining URL and POST variables in ServiceStack

Tags: rest, routes, servicestack

I am trying to convert an existing wcf rest api to ServiceStack, and having issues right out of the gate:

```
[Route("foo/{userId}","POST")]
public class MyInputModel : IReturnVoid
{
    public string userId { get; set; }
    public SomeOtherObject properties { get; set; }
}
```

The intention here is that I would provide the userId in the url, and an instance of SomeOtherObject in the post body. The error I get is

```
<Message>Could not deserialize 'application/xml' request using MyInputModel'
Error: System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: 
Error in line 1 position 42. Expecting element 'MyInputModel' 
from namespace 'blahblahblah'.. Encountered 'Element'  with name 
'SomeOtherObject', namespace 'http://blahblahblah'.
```

The only things I can think of are to wrap my xml in a `MyInputModel` to make the serializer happy. This is not really an option for backwards compatibility.

I could also modify `SomeOtherObject` to be the top level input model, and put a `UserId` property in there, but this also feels suboptimal since it is an object used throughout the api, and is really not tied to a user id. It is also already published independently, so it would be painful to make changes there.

Is there any way to indicate that the root element of the posted data will be a `SomeOtherObject` insted of a `MyInputModel`? In WebApi this would be with the `[FromBody]` attributes and whatnot. Does servicestack have anything similar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The purpose of a DTO is to auto-generate the wire format which is why [ServiceStack](http://www.servicestack.net/) requires the Request DTO to match the shape of the incoming request. Part of what makes ServiceStack so productive is that it's a code-first web service framework which encourages starting from **C# and projecting out**, i.e. your clients should bind to your web service outputs and not the other way round of mapping code-first models to existing schema inputs.

Having said that, the [Serialization / Deserialization wiki page](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Serialization-deserialization) lists the different ways to override ServiceStack's default request binding with your own.

#### Access HTTP Request variables in any Service or Filter

Not everything needs to be mapped to a DTO as any HTTP Variable can still be accessed from the [IHttpRequest](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Interfaces/ServiceHost/IHttpRequest.cs) available from any service or filter, i.e:

```
base.Request.QueryString
base.Request.FormData
base.Request.Headers[name]
base.Request.PathInfo
base.Request.AbsoluteUri
```

Comment: That actually makes a lot of sense. If I was designing this service from scratch, I would definitely do things differently, however my hands are somewhat tied by the existing api. In my case I can just make the Input Model `SomeOtherObject` and read the Id from the path.

Comment: I can't route to it that way, however because I need UserId to be in the url path, but `SomeOtherObject` Does not have that property. I really don't want to write a custom deserializer.

Comment: You can fetch it off the queryString i.e [Route("/foo")] and `/foo?userId=...`. Otherwise I think we'll need to add a [Route("/foo/{*ignore*}")] wildcard property in ServiceStack. [Raise an issue](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/issues) if you want this (so we don't lose track of it).

Comment: Ok just added the `{ignore}` feature [in this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/814f5872b8cf07875ba71cd516d78e6acf1764de), available in the next release of ServiceStack.

Comment: I did it for now with a custom Model Binder. Once I can update to the new version, that ignore route should make it much less precarious. Thanks!