# How do I handle multipart form data using ServiceStack?

Tags: servicestack

I am writing a service to process requests sent from the browser using mutlipart/formdata encoding of the files.

I see that I can get access to the raw input stream by decorating my request DTO with the interface IRequiresRequestStream and providing a Property called RequestStream.  But doing this seems to mean that I can't get any request properties filled in, even those that are contained within the URL.  For example, I have my request's route set up as follows

```
[Route("/document/{Type}/{Id}", "GET,PUT,POST/DELETE")]
public class UploadFileRequest : IReturn<UploadFileResponse>, IRequiresRequestStream
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }

    public Stream RequestStream { get; set; }
}
```

When I send a PUT request to this service, I see that the RequestStream property is set as I would like it to be, but the Id and Type properties are null.  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/servicestack/l9qFvZNbuT0/dwyRQKBhmlMJ seems to indicate that this will occur.

Is there any way to get at the route parameters and still access the request stream?  Even then it seems I'll need to handle parsing the form data, but hopefully I can find a library to do that easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Combining URL and POST variables in ServiceStack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14987069/combining-url-and-post-variables-in-servicestack) actually helped resolve this.  There are properties FormData and Files on the Request object accessible from within the service, and they contain the information that is needed.  So the DTO doesn't contain the RequestStream property or implement the IRequiresRequestStream interface